# Computing intersection in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

The real time collision detection book has the following equation.

```
// Compute the t value for the directed line ab intersecting the plane
Vector ab = b - a;
t = (p.d - Dot(p.n, a)) / Dot(p.n, ab);
```

So I have that currently as

```
GLKVector3 abD = GLKVector3Subtract(b, a);

GLKVector3 planeD = GLKVector3Make(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
GLKVector3 planeN = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

//t = (p.d - Dot(p.n, a)) / Dot(p.n, ab);

float dotPbA = GLKVector3DotProduct(planeN, a);
float dotPbAbD = GLKVector3DotProduct(planeN, abD);

GLKVector3 nominator = GLKVector3SubtractScalar(planeD, dotPbA);

GLKVector3 t = GLKVector3DivideScalar(nom, dotPbAbD);
// float t = nominator / dotPbA
```

**I need t as a float. What do I do?** I know in glm or something like that it will just be using operators.

Will length of GLKVector3 t give me what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `p.d` is the distance of the plane from the origin and therefore is not a *vector*, but a *scalar*, i.e. a `float`.

Then you can compute

```
float planeD = ...
GLKVector3 planeN = ...

GLKVector3 abD = GLKVector3Subtract(b, a);
float dotPbA = GLKVector3DotProduct(planeN, a);
float dotPbAbD = GLKVector3DotProduct(planeN, abD);

float t = (planeD - dotPbA)/dotPbAbD;
```

Comment: AH planeD as a float .. I had it as equation of the plane I think.

Comment: That code runs but im not getting a value of T back between 0 and 1 when it should

Comment: @Andrew: What is your input data? The formula seems to be correct.

Comment: Should I submit a new question?

Comment: @Andrew: It depends. If you think that I have answered your question and you have a different problem, then post a new question. - If you think there might be a problem with my answer then we can try to figure it out here.

Comment: Its hard to say, But you answer is correct anyway. It cant be wrong. Ill post a new question with the new code and link in here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588875/screen-coord-to-worldray-and-position

Comment: @Andrew: I could answer this question due to some math/geometry knowledge, but I have no experience with OpenGL, GLKit etc. - But of course, if you add a project download link to your new question, that might help that *somebody* can answer that question.